# The channeldispatcher is unable to open its ichannellistener

Tags: c#, wcf, delegates, servicehost

I am starting out with WCF. I have created two console apps (server and client) that work without any issues but since moving them onto forms I'm having all kinds of problems. I had a look here and elsewhere on the net, I can't seem to find anything that can help me with my issue. I honestly don't understand the issue but I think it may have something to do with my datatypes (they're under different namespaces)?

Here's my Server code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    ModelDataServer Server;
    public ScraperForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Server = new ModelDataServer(); // Opened Here
        Server.Scraper = this;
    }
}

[ServiceContract]
public interface IModelData
{
    [OperationContract]
    ArrayList GetData();
}

[ServiceBehavior(UseSynchronizationContext=false)]
public class ModelDataServer : IModelData
{
    ServiceHost Host;
    public DataModel Model { private get; set; }

    public ModelDataServer()
    {
        Host = new ServiceHost(typeof (ModelDataServer), 
            new Uri[]
            {
                new Uri("http://localhost:8000")
            });

        Host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IModelData),
            new BasicHttpBinding(),
            "ModelData");

        Host.Open();    // Error Points Here!!!
    }

    public ArrayList GetData()
    {
        return Model.GetData();
    }

    public void CloseServer()
    {
        Host.Close();
    }
}
```

Here's my Client code:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IModelData
{
    [OperationContract]
    ArrayList GetData();
}

[ServiceBehavior(UseSynchronizationContext = false)]
public class ModelDataClient
{
    ChannelFactory<IModelData> HttpFactory;
    IModelData HttpProxy;

    public ModelDataClient()
    {
        HttpFactory = new ChannelFactory<IModelData>(
            new BasicHttpBinding(),
            new EndpointAddress("http://localhost:8000/ModelData"));

        HttpProxy = HttpFactory.CreateChannel();
    }

    public ArrayList GetData()
    {
        return HttpProxy.GetData();
    }
}
```

Here's the error I'm recieving (points to where I'm opening the ServiceHost):

```
The ChannelDispatcher at 'http://localhost:8000/ModelData' with contract(s) '"IModelData"' is unable to open its IChannelListener.
```

P.S. I have been struggling to get delegates to work outside of something I've done in a tutorial. If anyone can suggest a better way that uses delegates instead of passing my form class into the other class that would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is most likely related to namespace issues.  For illustration issues, let's assume your server project's namespace is `ServerApp`, and your client's namespace is `ClientApp`.  You define `IModelData` in both applications, which means you have `ServerApp.IModelData` and `ClientApp.IModelData`.  Even though the code is identical, these are two separate interfaces (because of the namespace).

So you're trying to pass `ClientApp.IModelData` to the service, and it's expecting `ServerApp.IModelData`.

You can solve this by moving the interface `IModelData` to its own assembly and having the server app and the client app both reference this third assembly.  That's what we do at work - all of our service contracts are in a separate assembly (two, actually, but that's a different story).

A couple of other things to note:

Unless your client is also hosting a service, you can remove the `[ServiceContract]` attribute from the class.  Clients don't need that.

In your server app, what is `Server.Scraper = this;` for?  It appears to be assigning the Form to a property `Scraper` in the service, but I don't see that property in your code.  Additionally, services don't really use properties (I think I saw somewhere that you could do it, but it wasn't intuitive).  I don't think you'd want to assign the entire form to the service, as service's in and of themselves don't usually have UIs - they supply data and receive data from the service.